# Windows displays "No playback devices"

Tags: windows-7, audio

What I've tried:

1. I installed the drivers
2. Tried adding legacy hardware
3. Tried to re-flash bios

But no success. Is there any way to get the audio working? Like forcing to give output or something else?

Comment: You really need to proide more details before you can be helped. As it is, your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Still I've something you can try, try to [stream audio to your mobile device.](https://techwiser.com/stream-audio-from-pc-to-android) (I've myself used Soundwire). If you are successful, it'll shortlist problems to two  — 1. Driver issue/2. Hardware problem.

Comment: I already tried sound wire is saying error opening audio input device and play silence thread has died.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just want audio from my pc but in playback devices there is no speaker device.

Comment: I also found out that there is no hd audio device in device manager just nvidia audio.

Comment: Turned out that my sound card was damaged(intergrated).